# Android ListView Not Displaying Animation On Touch?

Tags: java, android, listview

Every list view I've ever used automatically provided animation change functionality when I would press an item within the list. I.e it would get dark and sink in a little. However, the one I'm currently working on is not functioning the same way. I was wondering if someone could tell me why.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private MenuAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new MenuAdapter();
        for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
            mAdapter.addItem("Food Item " + i);
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                mAdapter.addSeparatorItem("Category " + i);
            }
        }
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
        private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
        private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

        private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private ArrayList<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        public MenuAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void addItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
            mData.add(item);
            // save separator position
            mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                switch (type) {
                    case TYPE_ITEM:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                        break;
                    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item2, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here, because of using ViewHolder pattern. I believe viewholder theme might be different from existing theme. If you want use ViewHolder pattern you have to do the animation manually. Please remove and try.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I went ahead and made something from the ground up not using the view holder and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to rebuild my own solution from the ground up. This is much simpler than any demo code I've seen to create list views with headers. Granted I will be using a different layout as opposed to simply changing the color, but it's still a working concept.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<MenuObject> objects = new ArrayList<MenuObject>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            MenuObject tempObject;
            if(i % 5 == 0)
            tempObject = new MenuObject
                    (MenuObject.ObjectType.Category_Header, "Category " + i, "0");

            else tempObject = new MenuObject
                    (MenuObject.ObjectType.Food_Item, "Item " + i, "0");

            objects.add(tempObject);
        }

        ListAdapter theAdapter = new MenuAdapter(this, objects);
        ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    }

    class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuObject> {

        public MenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MenuObject> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.row_layout, values);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

            MenuObject obj = getItem(position);

            if(obj.m_Type == MenuObject.ObjectType.Category_Header) {
                TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                theTextView.setText(obj.m_Name);
                theView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB51202"));
            }

            else {
                TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                theTextView.setText(obj.m_Name);
            }

            return theView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your confirmation, Once we remove the ViewHolder pattern. It's working fine. Because viewholder theme is different from normal existing behavior.

So the code should be like this,

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

            MenuObject obj = getItem(position);

            if(obj.m_Type == MenuObject.ObjectType.Category_Header) {
                TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                theTextView.setText(obj.m_Name);
                theView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB51202"));
            }

            else {
                TextView theTextView = (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                theTextView.setText(obj.m_Name);
            }

            return theView;
        }
```